# Calculating the integral of a nonnegative function incase of a general measure space.

Tags: proof-writing, definition, solution-verification

I have the following givens:

Let $f$ be a nonnegative function on a measure space $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ and suppose that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$. for each $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ define $$\nu(E) = \int_{E} f d\mu.$$

And I am trying to prove that $\nu$ is an extended real-valued function from $\mathfrak{M}$ to $[0,\infty].$ but I know that the definition of the integral of a nonnegative function $f$ differs from the case of Lebesgue integral as we are in a general measure space. my question is:

Is $\int_{E} f d\mu $ still equals to $f \mu (E)$  as incase of Lebesgue measure?If so why? because this will prove that  $\nu$ is an extended real-valued function from $\mathfrak{M}$ to $[0,\infty],$ which is what I want.

Comment: In other words,you want prove $\nu$ is a measure?

Comment: I want just the first part of the definition of measure, not all of it @SL_MathGuy

Comment: The integral of any unsigned measurable function $f$ is given by, $$\int_{X}f d\mu = sup \int_{X} s d\mu$$, where supremum is taken over all simple functions $s$ s.t $0<s\leq f$

Comment: So, how to write the prove rigorously? I think the idea to some extent clear in my mind but just want to be sure. @SL_MathGuy

Comment: This is just how we define the integral for unsigned functions just like we define the Riemann integral of a function. Moreover I don't understand why you use the term 'extended'. In this case, $\nu$ is a measure; so the co domain is [0,1] . Hence, + $\infty$ is clearly not allowed. Therefore; it's not needed to call $\nu$ an extended real-valued function.

Comment: I am using the definition of a measure given on pg.338 of "Real Analysis" 4th edition by Royden and Fitzpatrick which contains the word "extended" @SL_MathGuy

Comment: So if we want to write a proof in a rigor way of this part, how can we write it? @SL_MathGuy

Comment: @SL_MathGuy I am sorry, the 1 at the end of the interval was a typo, it should be $\infty,$ I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\nu(E) \not\in [0,+\infty]$. i.e: $\nu(E)<0$. So, $\int_E fd \mu = sup \int_E s d\mu<0$, the supremum is taken over all simple functions $0<s \leq f$.

By definition of the integral of unsigned simple functions, $\int_Es d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i \mu(E_i)$, where $c_i \in [0, \infty]$ and {$E_i$} is a measurable partition of $E$.

What can we say about $\int_Es d\mu$?. This is clearly non-negative since it's a finite sum of non-negative terms ($c_i \geq 0$ & $\mu(E_i) \geq 0$since $\mu$ is a measure).

Therefore, sup $\int_E s d\mu<0$ for all $0<s \leq f$ , is a contradiction. $\nu(E)\geq 0$